# Integrating LibYUV to my Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, precompiled, libyuv

I was wondering how do I include libyuv library to my Android Studio Project. I have the "libyuv_static.a" file which is a pre-compiled binary file but I did everything to include it in my project. I created a folder inside src/main named jniLibs and puted the binary file inside the folder but in runtime it doesn't load the library and it gives me this:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libyuv2rgb
>   from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.myproject-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.myproject-1]:
>   findLibrary returned null

. Could someone please share his/her experience.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include a native library into an Android project, you have to get a .so file (shared library), not a .a (static library).

ie. you should end up with `src/main/jniLibs/<abi>/libyuv_shared.so` with `<abi>` being *armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64* (any architecture your app and lib support).

Answer (score 1):

There is an Android package now: https://github.com/crow-misia/libyuv-android, installable from mavenCentral:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.github.crow-misia.libyuv:libyuv-android:0.25.0'
}
```

For usage see https://github.com/crow-misia/libyuv-android/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/app/MainActivity.kt